# Subtracting from today only if other cell is empty

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to track the amount of time it takes to pay an invoice from the date of submission F11=submission date G11=Date Paid H11=totals days. The formula will be in H11 where F11 is substracted from todays day only if there's no date in G11

I was trying this formula, but it's not working, I am getting blank.

```
=IF(OR(F11<>"",(TODAY()-F11)),"",G11-F11)
```

This formula works =IF(G11="",today()-F11,G11-F11) but when both cells are empty, I receive a random 45071 number.

Thanks for you assistance

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser . It's a bit unclear what's in F and what's in G. Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1785939/edit) and explain what you are subtracting and maybe add a sample/screenshot of what you have.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to do with the `OR` there... which is why it doesn't work.

You need a simple `IF` like this:

```
=IF(F11="","",IF(G11="",TODAY()-F11,G11-F11))
```

- `IF` cell `F11` is empty then output empty
- `IF` `F11` is not empty, but `G11` is empty
- *value_if_true* (G11 is empty): `TODAY()-F11`
- *value_if_false*: `G11-F11`